# How to install Maven integration plugin in Eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm trying to install Maven integration plugin in Eclipse Helios via Marketplace, but I'm receiveing "cannot satisfy dependency" error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
  Missing requirement: async-http-client 1.6.5.20130531-2315 (com.ning.async-http-client 1.6.5.20130531-2315) requires 'package org.slf4j 1.6.2' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Archetype Common Bundle 1.4.0.20130531-2315 (org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common 1.4.0.20130531-2315)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime [1.4.0,1.5.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common [1.4.0.20130531-2315]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Embedded Maven Runtime Bundle 1.4.0.20130531-2315 (org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime 1.4.0.20130531-2315)
    To: bundle com.ning.async-http-client [1.6.5,1.6.6)
```

Do you have any ideas how it could be done?
Unfortunately, upgrading Eclipse is not an option in my case.

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade "slf4j" by donwloading `org.slf4j:1.6.2` and copying it into %ECLIPSE_HOME%/plugins?

Comment: That usually mean some incompatibility with some already installed components. You could also try updating your plugins.

Comment: @mabbas nope, didn't help. Tried download it from Maven site, their official website... All remains the same.

Comment: @rlegendi I just downloaded Eclipse and installed all plugins so I don't think that the problem is here.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this problem? Could you update the question if you did? From the look of the marketplace bugs page hundreds of people are getting the same problem, and this is the first hit on google...

Comment: @Paul I migrated to IntelliJ IDEA, but this is not the real solution. Also, may be some newer version of Eclipse will work with maven.

Answer (score 61):

I believe you must be trying the following URL in the update site:

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Try using:

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

Comment: 404 on both links. Link rot after 2 months :(

Comment: the provided url only works within eclipse-install. it does not work within browser

Comment: `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3` it works!! You need to go to `Install New Software` option and add this URL you will get it through.

Comment: How can  i upvote this twice, because this was the link which helped me last time too..

Answer (score 3):

In your install manager, check "Contact all updates sites" . This should resolve the problem as sometimes dependencies come form different sites.

Comment: checked, but nothing. BTW, I tried to install it via Eclipse Marketplace, not "Install New Software".

Answer (score 0):

Dated : 2015-June-04
I was trying to do the same for IBM RAD 8.5.0 which is built on Eclipse 3.6 i.e Helios Platform.
I tried using the below link and it works fine.
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4

Also uncheck the "Show only the latest versions of available software" this gives you all the versions that are compatable with your current version.